# Is is possible to store warnings in a variable for using later?

Tags: r

I'm writing some code in r to read excel and send an email upon success. I would like to capture any warnings that are generated when reading the file (e.g. when expecting a date but getting a text) as the file has some inconsistencies so I want to include these warnings as part of the email.

I'm new to R and couldn't find the answer in searching so apologies if this has been answered before.

So far I have tried manipulating the warning messages into a string variable, and it seems to work fine but only when I run a snippet of the code (Ctrl+Enter). If I run all it doesn't capture the warning message.

```
suppressWarnings(library("readxl"))

success = TRUE
readIssues <- "No file read issues detected"

tryCatch( {
  #read excel file
  pct <<- read_excel("Filename.xls")
}
, error = function(m) {success <<- FALSE}
)

readIssues <- attr(warnings(),"name")
readIssues <- paste(readIssues,sep=" ",collapse="\n")
```

I expect readIssues to store the warning messages so I can use them later in the code when generating the email (e.g. "Expecting date in AF1059 / R1059C32: got 'some text'").

I'm curious as to why it runs fine when I select everything and Ctrl+Enter but not when I do Ctrl+Alt+R.

Comment: Your call to `attr()` should look like `attr(readIssues, "name") <- warnings()`.  And your `tryCatch()` appears to be missing the closing `)`.  Start there and see what success you have.

Comment: Thanks, added the bracket. I tried changing it to the above and it still does not assign the warning messages to the variable. Interestingly enough it sets it to blank instead. I'm guessing that warnings are not generated until the entire code has finished running. That could explain why it assigns correctly if I run these lines again after running the full code first.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of  `readIssues <- capture.output(pct <<- read_excel("Filename.xls"), type = "message")` Evaluate `?capture.output` to see if it could help.

Comment: This is a *highly* unorthodox and convoluted way of dealing with errors. No need for any of this; if you want to catch and handle errors just return an appropriate value from the `error` handler. And certainly don’t perform global assign inside it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the input. I'm actually trying to handle errors differently from warnings, and adding a warning handler in the tryCatch doesn't seem to return anything. Does your suggestion work the same way in this case?

Comment: @xrslxn It works. For example, you can write `pct = tryCatch(withCallingHandlers(read_excel('filename'), warning = handler), error = function (.) NULL)`. This is idiomatic R: the assignment is done *outside* the function call, and in case of error, `NULL` is assigned (change that to whatever’s convenient for you). Your handler function will need to do global `<<-` assignment, and that’s OK (since we need it here).

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to apply useCallingHandlers within the tryCatch, and then extract the required warning messages. Posting here in case anyone else is looking for the answer:

Credit to this [Post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-June/052132.html)

Code:

```
suppressWarnings(library("readxl"))

success = TRUE
readIssues <- "No file read issues detected"

myWarnings <- NULL

wHandler <- function(w) {
  myWarnings <<- c(myWarnings,w)
  invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
}

tryCatch( {
pct <- withCallingHandlers(read_excel("Filename.xls"), warning = wHandler)
}
, error = function(m) {success <<- FALSE}
)

pickOut <- sapply(myWarnings, function(x) class(x)=="character")
readIssues <- myWarnings[pickOut]
readIssues <- paste(readIssues,sep="\n",collapse="\n")
```

Thanks all for the help!